# How to load javascript file1 first before javascript file2

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript file one with the functions and another with the eventlistener. This is how I declare them

```
<body>
    <script src="../script/Main%20Functions.js"></script>
    <script src="../script/Main-events.js"></script>
</body>
```

Main Functions.js

```
checklike(userId,postId);
function checkLike(userId, postId) {
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "../Main.asmx/get_liked",
        data: "{'userID':'" + userId + "', 'postID':'" + postId + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var result = response.d;
            console.log('ok');
            $.each(result, function (index, data) {
                var liked = data.liked;
                if (liked == true) {
                    $("#" + postId).prev().parent("button").css("background", "#ccc");
                }
                else {
                    $("#" + postId).prev().parent("button").css("background", "white");
                }
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Function Error "checkLike"');
        }

    });
}
```

Main-events.js

```
const d = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const D = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const logOut = d('.lOut h3');
const iFrame = d('#if1');
const alias = d('.codename-label h2');
const monito = d('.monito-label');
const monitoChecklists = D('.monito-checklist');
const displayPicture = d('#displayPic');
const btnReveal = d('.btn-reveal');
const btnSubmit = d('.btn-submit');
const btnLike = D('.buttonLike');
console.log('ok2');
btnLike.forEach(function (like) {
    like.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.log(this);
    })
});
```

but when I open the html the `console.log('ok2');` executes first not the `console.log('ok')` . Is there a way on telling the javascript to load specific file first before executing the file for `eventlistener`?

EDIT 1: The adding of `eventlistener` for the `btnLike` loads first before the javascript added the elemet on the page.

EDIT 2: Okay upon investigation

Before trying eventlistener I use this jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonLike', function () {
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    var id = $(this).find(".postID").attr("id");
    if (color == "rgb(204, 204, 204)") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        var number = parseInt($("#" + id).html().substring(0, $("#" + id).html().indexOf(" "))) - 1;
        if (number > 1) {
            number = number + " Likes";
        }
        else {
            number = number + " Like";
        }
        $("#" + id).html(number);
        Remove_Like(id);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ccc");
        var number = parseInt($("#" + id).html().substring(0, $("#" + id).html().indexOf(" "))) + 1;
        if (number > 1) {
            number = number + " Likes";
        }
        else {
            number = number + " Like";
        }
        $("#" + id).html(number);
        Add_Like(id);
    }
});
```

it works fine and I found out that it uses the `document` and check if the `target` has class name `.buttonLike` am i right?

Comment: What is in your Main-events.js file? Only  console.log('ok2'); ?

Comment: The two script files are loaded in the correct order, but the Ajax call is happening asynchronously. The first console statement is executed when the Ajax call has finished

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @PatrickHund I will post the real dilemma i'm facing

Comment: @PatrickHund please see the edited version.

Comment: Why are you not using the code starting from `btnLike.forEach...` inside the ajax callback (with other words: place it in `MainFunctions.js` instead of `Main-events.js` ? It would avoid to use a small hacky workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax` is **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML.

So, being asynchronous, the `console.log` are not being called in order. And as `ajax` might be taking a while to get called, the `'ok2'` is getting called first.

The solution to this is to call the `'ok2'` inside the `success` or `done` method of `$.ajax`

Comment: please re-read the edited version. So if I follow this logic, I need to add the `eventlistener` on the success?

Comment: why are you calling `checklike(userId,postId);` at the begining and not in the `addEventListener` method

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Try calling the `checklike()` method inside the `addEventListener ` method. Seems more logical

Comment: Is that really the right way? because when the page load first. It gets the `post` (facebook like) and check how many likes this post have. Then create the element.

Comment: I got your problem now. What you should do is, is to create the element inside the success method and then add the event listener to it. That'd solve it.

Comment: @nikamanish but wouldn't it repeating adding the eventlistener again and again?

Comment: instead of doing the `btnLike.forEach`, you could just put the listener in the `success` method. Would yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load another js file in your ajax call than you can use this

jQuery's $.getScript() is buggy sometimes, so I use my own implementation of it like:

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
if (typeof someObject == 'undefined') $.loadScript('url_to_someScript.js', function(){
    //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
});
```

or simply

You can listen to the script's load event, and do things with the results as you would. So:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //do stuff with the script
};
script.src = something;

document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
```

Another option

will fire when a script is finished loading.

You will not be able to do something like:

```
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
<script src="/bar.js"></script>
<script>
function alertonload(src){
   console.log(src+' is loaded');
}
scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++){
    scripts[i].onload = function(){ alertonload(scripts[i].src); };
}
</script>
```

This is pure conjecture and speculation; I have not tried it and there's probably better ways to write it, but this will not do what you're looking to do. EDIT: The scripts are loaded as the browser sees them, not after the fact. They will be loaded before this occurs.